# can't find command 'linux16', need to update Dell BIOS. use startup disk?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, uefi, bios

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, Dell has dropped support for linux except for one server line, and none of [these solutions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS) work because the `linux16` command is gone from grub2.

How can the final steps involving `linux16` be replaced to work with grub2?

Ubuntu was installed with UEFI active if that helps.

---

Is it possible to change to CSM in the BIOS from UEFI, boot with a Ubuntu USB startup disk, and use the non-UEFI grub to use `linux16`?

If so, should the bios update files be on my HDD (encrypted) or the bootable USB?  What else?

Comment: I'm confused. what exactly are you trying to do? upgrade your BIOS? replace your BIOS with UEFI? (that last one is a terrible idea and is most likely impossible)

Comment: @strugee Thank you for looking strugee!  I'm trying to upgrade my bios, but I can't do the last steps recommended in the links above because grub2/efi doesn't have `linux16`, necessary to load an image in 16 bit mode.  Do you know how to do this with grub2/efi?  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: OK, so if you're trying to update your BIOS, why are you talking about EFI?

Comment: @strugee Good point.  I just double checked my `/boot` mount, and it is not efi.  Do you know how to resolve this?  Thank you so much in advance! (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horrible approach.  It's almost as bad as Dell's support for the best kernel in existence.

This is how you do it to keep your sanity:

1. Install unetbootin
2. Make a USB FreeDOS bootable
3. Put your Dell BIOS file on the USB
4. Load FreeDOS in safe mode
5. Execute the BIOS files from C:\

Oh Dell, if it weren't for the fact that I received this laptop for free, you'd get none of my money, and you'll get no more until you support the ideal OS.