# Updating of drivers and bios

Tags: laptop, bios, zorin

I have a Dell Latitude D820 laptop.
With Zorin 12.1 64 Bit system.

Are there any bios and driver updating programs for Zorin 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

A new version is Zorin OS 12.2 is out:

http://zoringroup.com/blog/2017/09/08/zorin-os-12-2-released-our-most-advanced-operating-system-ever-2/

Otherwise you can get updates of/to the OS (which includes the Linux kernel, which in turn includes device drivers) using the built-in update tool.  One way is to do it in the command line (which I personally prefer):

Open a Terminal (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T), then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(you may be asked for your own or the `root` password, please follow the prompts).

Your BIOS upgrades separately, and it is more difficult.  Here is a related answer:

[can't find command 'linux16', need to update Dell BIOS. use startup disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107361/cant-find-command-linux16-need-to-update-dell-bios-use-startup-disk?answertab=votes#tab-top)